# ZKTco Sdk Not Supported in Web Application

Tags: .net, web, model-view-controller, configuration, sdk

I'm working on web attendance and staff portal and need to configure ZKTeco devices with IP. Device is working fine with desktop application but when I'm using SDK with .NET mvc project it shows the following error.

[image: i am using IiS manager]
I'm using IiS manager. I registered com classes and references added in solution.
[image: i am using zkemkeeper.dll]
I'm using zkemkeeper.dll

I searched on google that I have to use SDK Online but unable to find it anywhere. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Online SDK is restricted to public use form the manufacturer.  For connecting the biometric devices with your web application, you have to implement the web api with RESTFul url and communicate through HTTP. Refer http://zkteco.tech/application/biometric-web-api.html for the api documentation